# Golismero scanner is not reporting

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I'm trying to use Golismero scanner which I found out to be a very good web scanner for vulnerabilities with lots of tests and tools, etc. It is a scanner that comes with BlackArch Linux and Kali Linux. There is an option to generate a HTML report by typing `-o` like:

```
golismero scan somesite.com -o report.html
```

For some reason that I don't know the reports are not being created though it displays "reporting..." at stdout. I also thought that was a permission problem so I ran it as sudo but also didn't worked. Does anyone here have use it and know how to solve this?

Comment: This question is best suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/). However did you try specifying the full path? Something like /tmp/report.html?

Comment: wow, that' will sound silly but trying full path just worked, hehe, thanks mate